# incrementar el valor de un arreglo de acuerdo a su indice en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Que tal amigos estoy realizando un reto de codewars, el cual consiste en agregar el valor del indice (este iniciando en 0) a cada valor de la posición del arreglo.

Y tengo una solución, pero por alguna razón no me lo acepta o tal vez lo estoy realizando de manera errónea.

Básicamente estas son las instrucciones:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es mi solución en el codewars

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi solucione en un archivo .js es de la siguiente manera

```js
//arreglo
nums = [4, 6, 9, 1, 3]
//Mi procedimiento
nums.map((element, index) => {
    index++
    let result = (element + index);
    console.log(result % 10);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `.map` retorna un nuevo array, no lo modifica, de manera que siempre vas a tener que hacer `nuevoArray = viejoArray.map(...)`. Además, dentro del callback del `.map()` tiene que haber un `return` si se utilizan llaves, sino no es necesario.

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const res = nums.map((e, i) => (++i + e) % 10);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una opción, calcula el número + su índice, iniciando el for a partir de 1 en lugar de 0, y si el número tiene más de un dígito solo extrae el último para el resultado en el array. Creo que es todo lo que pide la letra, son varias cosas en realidad, espero te sirva.

```
const test = [4, 6, 9, 1, 3]; //Array para pruebas

function numberAndIndex(test) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= test.length; i++) {
    let auxNumberToAdd = "";
    let numberToAdd = "";
    if ((test[i - 1] + i).toString().length > 1) {
      auxNumberToAdd = (test[i - 1] + i).toString();
      numberToAdd = auxNumberToAdd.slice(auxNumberToAdd.length - 1);
      test[i - 1] = Number(numberToAdd);
    } else {
      test[i - 1] = test[i - 1] + i;
    }
  }
  return test;
}
```